# How can display the contents of each menu?JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/57ouufrq/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">MENU1</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU2</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU4</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU1</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU2</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.content .c1:first-child').show();

    $('.content').on('click', 'c1', function () {   // this=c1
               //function to display the contents
    });        
});
```

I want that when a user clicks on a menu to display specific content.
For example:click on the `MENIU3` display `CONTENT FOR MENU 3`and rest to be hidden.

I do not know how this function should be designed so that it works.

You can help me with some ideas please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/57ouufrq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the target c1 using its index

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $c1s = $('.content .c1');

    $('.container').on('click', '.menu', function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $c1s.hide();
        $c1s.eq(index).show();
    });

});
```

```css
.container {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
.content {
    float:left;
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
}
.c1 {
    display:none;
}

.content .c1:first-child{display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">MENU1</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU2</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu">MENU4</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU1</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU2</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".container .menu").each(function(index) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(".content .c1").hide();
        $(".content .c1").eq(index).show();        
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v4Lgwuma/

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu" data-target="content_1">MENU1</div>
    <div class="menu" data-target="content_2">MENU2</div>
    <div class="menu" data-target="content_3">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu" data-target="content_4">MENU3</div>
    <div class="menu" data-target="content_5">MENU4</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="content_1" class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU1</div>
    <div id="content_2" class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU2</div>
    <div id="content_3" class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div id="content_4" class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
    <div id="content_5" class="c1">CONTENT FOR MENU3</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.menu', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('target')).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ys5skg09/